# Is it possible to add a column scale to geopandas plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, geopandas

I was wondering whether a method or a parameter in a geopandas geodataframe plot exists so that its column attribute (once given) could be scaled according to some function (i.e.: log) during Map creation.

In problems regarding pandas plot, there are logx and logy attributes in the Pandas Plot that allow that kind of configuration. Once logy is set to True, even the colorbar follows the scaling factor (log). If possible, I would like similar behavior with the geopandas plot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scheme` keyword. It will allow you to set desired classification (binning) of your values. Geopandas 0.5.0 support all schemes provided by `mapclassify` so you can use one of them or define your own via `mapclassify.User_Defined`. That should also adjust legend.

```
gdf.plot(column='colname', scheme='headtail_breaks')

bins = [20, 30] # upper bounds of your bins
gdf.plot(column='colname', scheme='user_defined', bins=bins)
```

Alternatively you can make another column with log values and classify map based on that, but I understand that it might not be desirable method.

For description of classification methods see https://mapclassify.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html and for example of its implementation in Geopandas see http://geopandas.org/mapping.html?highlight=mapclassify#choosing-colors.

Comment: Dear martinfleis, could you add a code example of how I can do it? I tried here in my machine, and I resulted only in message errors.

Comment: @PhilipeRiskallaLeal your question should first contain an MRE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a way to apply a classifier over geopandas using the mapclassify library over geopandas geodataframe. Here I post a simple class containing a staticmethod which allows to evaluate and retrieve the classification object from a pandas/geopandas Series.

The classification object contains some attributes which can be passed to the plotting function of one's geopandas geodataframe.

The classification can also be altered, since there are several options solely in mapclassify library.

Here is a code snippet:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
import numpy as np


class matplotlib_custom_schemer(object):

    @ staticmethod

    def get_bins_for_transformed_data(series, transformation='log', 
                               mc_classifier='Fisher_Jenks_Sampled' , 
                               k=5, **kwd_for_mc_classifier):

        if not callable(transformation):
            import numpy as np
            if hasattr(np, transformation):
                transformation = getattr(np, transformation)
            else:
                print("User must supply a transformation function or a numpy function for it to work")

        series = transformation(series)

        import mapclassify as mc
        classifier = getattr(mc, mc_classifier)

        e = classifier(y=series, k=k, **kwd_for_mc_classifier)

        return e






# Getting classification bins

e = matplotlib_custom_schemer.get_bins_for_transformed_data(Temp[column].values, k=6)

ei = e.bins.tolist()

# Plotting with classified bins


Projection = ccrs.PlateCarree()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(3,4, figsize=(width, height), sharex=False, sharey=False, subplot_kw={'projection':Projection})


minx, miny, maxx, maxy = GeoDataFrame.total_bounds

GeoDataFrame.plot(ax=ax, 
          column='my_column_with_numerical_data', 
          legend=True, 
          markersize = 0.01,
          categorical=False,
          scheme='user_defined',
          classification_kwds={'bins':ei},
          linewidth=0.02,
          edgecolor='k',
          facecolor='white',
          legend_kwds={'loc': (1.05, 0.25), 
                       'bbox_transform':ax.transAxes,
                       'frameon': True , 
                       'markerscale':0.4,
                       'markersize':10,
                       'handletextpad':0.2,
                       'handlelength':0.15,
                       'labelspacing':0.2,
                       'fontsize':7.5} )


ax.set_extent((minx,  maxx, miny, maxy))

fig.show()
```

Feel free to update it.

Sincerely yours,

Philipe R. Leal